# how can I open the Facebook App for share a link on wp8?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8

I wonder how to open the official Facebook App for sharing an URI from my C# code on Windows Phone.
I finally solved it! It took me nearly two days to find the solution and it is not documented anywhere so that I would like to share my results with you:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:post?text=foo"));
```

But I want share post link from open app on device wp8.

Comment: can you please provide twitter launchuri also if you know..thanks